# How can I enable Shapefile GUI Loader in pgadmin3?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-3

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.1 with PostGIS 1.5.3 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I also installed pgadmin3 1.14.0-beta1, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66099/how-can-i-update-pgadmin3-to-v1-14) instructions.

If I remember correctly, when I installed PostGIS on Windows pgadmin automagically came with Shapefile GUI Loader plugin already installed. On Ubuntu however, the plugin drop down menu is empty.

[Instructions](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?url=archives/180-PgAdmin-III-1.13-change-in-plugin-architecture-and-PostGIS-Plugins.html) I found seems to be Windows specific.

Is there a way to install / enable it on Ubuntu?

Comment: there's a [`--with-gui` configure flag](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id2618826) if you install PostGIS from source, but I've never tried this so I can't say if it works

Comment: @MikeToews: Thanks. I noticed it in the docs as well now. Well worth remembering for the future but I'm still hoping to enable it in already installed stack.

Comment: I have the same problem. I was able to install the opengeo-postgis-shapeloader thru synaptic package but I can't see it in pgAdmin3. I'm using Xubuntu 10.04

Comment: I couldn't get the `--with-gui` flag to work on ubuntu. You could download the `OpenGeo` package http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/download/ and use the gui that comes with it, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a painless install, you might want to start over and use the [OpenGeo Suite version](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/usermanual/installation/linux/postgis-ubuntu.html) of PostGIS.

```
$sudo wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -
$sudo echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$sudo apt-get update
$apt-cache search opengeo
$sudo apt-get install opengeo-postgis
```

Or you could just install the shape loader instead of the whole postgis package.

```
$sudo apt-get install opengeo-postgis-shapeloader
```

It would be installed in /usr/sbin you need to make a symbolic link to $$PGBINDIR ( which in this case is in /usr/bin )

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/shp2pgsql-gui /usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
```

Finally, in your **plugins.ini** file:

> ```
> ;
> ; pgShapeLoader (Linux):
> ;
> Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
> Command=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui -U $$USERNAME -d $$DATABASE -p $$PORT -h $$HOSTNAME
> Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
> KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui
> Platform=unix
> ServerType=postgresql
> Database=Yes
> SetPassword=No
> ```

As you're using pgadmin3 1.14.0, I think you need to place the **plugins.ini** under **/usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/**. Lower versions put it under **/usr/share/pgadmin3/**

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried your second method and updated my `plugins.ini` file - unfortunately it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Hmmm... I took that plugins.ini file from the OpenGeo version. Maybe you have to set the parameters to match your current configuration? I just checked the package listings at pkgs.org. Could you verify if shp2pgsql is in your PGBINDIR?

Comment: How exactly could i verify that?

Comment: Could you run find and check if shp2pgsql-gui exists in your filesystem?

Comment: Changed my answer. Please check if it works this time. I'll test it on my box, too as soon as I get home.

Comment: Thanks for more hints. My `shp2pgsql-gui` exists in `/usr/bin`. It does work without any problems when I simply double click it. I already had symbolic link that you mention created. Also tried moving `plugins.ini` to `plugins.d` directory (which did't exist on my machine. Restarted Postgres and still no link to the loader in pgadmin :/

Comment: Also tried moving plugins.ini to plugins.d directory (which did't exist on my machine > Did you create the missing directories? Did some reading and found out that pgadmin3 1.14.0 expects the .ini files to be in /usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/ You might want to create those directories.

Comment: `plugins.d` directory didn't exist on my machine. Had to create it and then moved `ini` file there.

Comment: Oh... my bad. This is one tough problem. x_x

Comment: I'm officially out of ideas. Changing the platform in the plugins.ini from platform=linux to platform=unix fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for effort. Will try opengeo version for my next install.

Comment: Shouldn't it be wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: On my system (ubuntu 12.10), I only had to insert the plugins.ini definition. I think the plugin itself was installed with postgis from the ubuntugis-unstable ppa (see http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1210). There is therefore no need to install the opengeo version of postgis on more recent versions of Ubuntu, but do use the plugins.ini definition given above.

Comment: I faced the same issue with the plugin on Ubuntu 12.04. Followed similar steps outline above except for different file paths. I had to set PGBINDIR environment variable as well. I have explained the steps I followed in my blog post: http://www.staygeo.com/2013/05/enabling-postgis-shapefile-and-dbf.html

Comment: FYI  the first link doesn't point to where it used to.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe I'm having the same issue in 2014 with 12.04.

Neither the GUI nor command-line shapeloader install using the opengeo-suite.

I simply followed the noob-friendly directions on this website:
http://www.staygeo.com/2013/05/enabling-postgis-shapefile-and-dbf.html, which parallel the instructions by RK almost 2 years ago.

"Install opengeo-postgis2-shapeloader using this command at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install opengeo-postgis2-shapeloader
```

It gets installed in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin as shp2pgsql-gui. Now create a symbolic link for the same in /usr/bin directory. Prior to this you may want to check if the postgresql version you have is 9.2.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/shp2pgsql-gui /usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
```

Now it's the time to edit plugins.d file. Use the following command to open the file for editing:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/plugins.ini
```

Paste the following contents at the end of the file:

```
;
; pgShapeLoader (Linux):
;
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
Command=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui -U $$USERNAME -d $$DATABASE -p $$PORT -h $$HOSTNAME
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui
Platform=unix
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=No
```

Note: You may have to set the environment variable PGBINDIR on your machine. To check if the environment variable is already set type this on your terminal:

```
echo $PGBINDIR
```

If an empty line appears as a result, it indicates that environment variable is not set. You will have to set it to /usr/bin (the location where the symbolic link for shapefile loader resides). For that use this command:

```
PGBINDIR=/usr/bin
```

Once the above steps are done invoke pgAdmin III to see the 'PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader' listed under plugins."

***No copyright intended (it's well-written so I didn't paraphrase :).***

Comment: With my installation of PostGIS/QGIS from the `ubuntugis-stable` ppa the `shp2pgsql-gui` comes already installed, all I had to do was add the code to the `plugins.ini` file.

Answer (score 3):

This response may be late,but i had the same trouble and i found the solution.
Try this command on your terminal :

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/shp2pgsql /usr/bin/shp2pgsql
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the instructions [here](http://invariantproperties.com/2011/07/04/getting-started-on-postgis-in-action-on-ubuntu/). It's definitely a separate executable on Fedora. Also, have you tried:

sudo apt-get install shp2pgsql-gui?

Comment: I thought about sudo as well. Unfortunately response is: `Unable to locate package shp2pgsql-gui`. Thanks for other pointer - will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Step1. Create folder name: plugin.d in folder PgAminIII
Ex:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\pgsql\9.1\pgAdmin III\plugins.d
```

Step2. Create files config for app you need in new plugins folder

EX: postgis.shp2pgsql-gui

```
 psql
```

detai file: postgis.shp2pgsql-gui:

;
; PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui (Windows):
;

```
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader 2.0
Command="$$PGBINDIR\shp2pgsql-gui.exe" -h "$$HOSTNAME" -p $$PORT -U "$$USERNAME" -d "$$DATABASE" -W "$$PASSWORD"
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR\shp2pgsql-gui.exe
Platform=windows
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was meant to be Ubuntu/Linux specific..

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is found in the Ubuntu PostGIS repository, and the bottom of the [PostGIS Debian Instructions](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS22UbuntuPGSQL95Apt) covers how to install it:

Open terminal, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

(Note: this is coming from the main Ubuntu software repository, as it seems the PostgreSQL APT repository doesn't package SHP2PGSQL-GUI anymore...)

Now open the SHP2PGSQL application:

```
shp2pgsql-gui
```

Follow the on-screen prompts to load your data.

Answer (score 0):

The application name is **shp2pgsql-gui**, its located inside the **postgis-gui** package. Install it and search for it your linux programs. It start it outside of pgadmin3. This is the trick i use always.

`sudo apt-get install postgis-gui`

Answer (score 0):

Okay 2020
Ubuntu 18.04
Postgresql 10
postgis 2.5
pgadmin3 (written in php?) pgamdin4 seems to be python so havent figured out how to apply it to that yet.

to install the shapeloader
`sudo apt install postgis-gui`

`sudo vim /usr/share/pgadmin3/plugins.d/plugins.ini`
then add this to the end of plugins.ini

```
;
; pgShapeLoader (Linux):
;
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
Command=/usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui -U $$USERNAME -d $$DATABASE -p $$PORT -h $$HOSTNAME
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=/usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
Platform=unix
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=No
```

Thanks to [@Shmuck Jones](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/26238/shmuck-jones) for his answer

Answer (score -1):

I think the package postgis from the ubuntu repo will install everything you need, as explained in the last lines of https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt