# How can I enable PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader 2.0 plugin in PgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I am on Windows and I want to download/enable the plugin "PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader 2.0". I installed PostGIS 2.0 using StackBuilder of PostgreSQL installer.

Comment: during the stack builder process you should have recieved a dialogue box aksing to install the PostGIS Shapefile Loader. Did you see this and say 'No' - then that is where it has gone wrong. You might be able to find the exe in the C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.x\bin folder

Comment: put some process photos before facing problem could help you get more useful advice.

Comment: [How can I enable Shapefile GUI Loader in pgadmin3?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16181/how-can-i-enable-shapefile-gui-loader-in-pgadmin3) (on Ubuntu, though it contains links to the Windows help from BostonGIS)

Comment: All the comment's give me the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need - this is added to plugins.ini file and enables the shapefile and dbf loader.  I'm using postgre 9.2 and postgis 2.0.

```
;
;PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui (Windows):
;
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
Command="$$PGBINDIR\postgisgui\shp2pgsql-gui.exe" -h "$$HOSTNAME" -p $$PORT -U "$$USERNAME" -d "$$DATABASE" -W "$$PASSWORD"
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR\postgisgui\shp2pgsql-gui.exe
Platform=windows
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=Yes
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the plugins.ini file is located in the pgAdmin III\plugins.d folder. However, with a separate install of PostGIS, you'll find another file in the plugins.d folder: postgis.shp2pgsql-gui.ini. It has the same content as Simplest2remember mentioned in his answer. Either this content is saved in the plugins.ini file, or you have the postgis.shp2pgsql-gui.ini file: both scenarios will dispose the PostGIS GUI in the list of plugins in pgAdmin III.

Comment: If this does not work for you, you can also start the loader from outside of pgAdmin: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225079/23263