# OSM data as Postgresql dump

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

Does anywhere host the OSM planet DB as a Postgresql dump? I have tried using `osm2pgsql` but I have limited processing capabilities so it is never finishing. I do not have bandwidth limitations so ideally I would like to download a Postgresql dump or another format that does not require as much processing. Data in a torrent would be ideal.

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/ and use pgadmin 4  > http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217456/shapefile-loader-in-pgadmin-4

Comment: @Mapperz there is no way that will be quicker than piping a pg_dump file at the command line.

Comment: I was also shocked at how much processing is involved with osm2pgsql and pbf format.  I ended up using osmosis in Google compute engine,  and pg_dumping that.

Comment: but you need a pg_dump for the data you are interested in. At least the shape to postgis get the data you want in the database quickly.

Comment: Maybe https://imposm.org/ is an alternative to osm2pgsql? With less resources needed?